# Are homeomorphic representations isomorphic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $V_1, V_2$ be two finite-dimensional real representations. Suppose $f: V_1 \to V_2$ is a $G$-equivariant homeomorphism. Can one conclude that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are isomorphic representations?

Comment: Maybe you assume the group is finite? Otherwise take $\mathbf{Z}$ acting on $\mathbf{R}$ by powers of $x\mapsto 2x$, resp. $x\mapsto 3x$.

Comment: @Ycor Thanks! I have editted the question.

Comment: This is true if $f$ is an isometry, since surjective isometries are affine transformations.  (I have known that as the Banach–Mazur theorem, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem) seems to disagree.)

Comment: This seems false for cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{C}$. There are conjugate characters. Their action is "the same up to conjugation," and so they are equivariantly homeomorphic, no?

Comment: @LSpice I think being isometry is a too strong assumption.

Comment: @GevaYashfe Are they isomorphic as real representations?

Comment: @GevaYashfe, as @‍UVIR [suggests](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419709/are-homeomorphic-representations-isomorphic#comment1077867_419709), conjugate *complex* characters are isomorphic as *real* representations precisely *via* the conjugate!

Comment: Sorry and thanks, I misread the question.

Comment: @LSpice $x \mapsto \operatorname{sign}(x) |x|^{ \log 3/\log 2}$.

Comment: @WillSawin, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419709/are-homeomorphic-representations-isomorphic#comment1077872_419709); I had forgotten that there's no winding about the origin for $\mathbb R$ (and deleted my original comment—which, for the record, asked how to realise the homeomorphism of @‍YCor's [representations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419709/are-homeomorphic-representations-isomorphic#comment1077858_419709)—once I realised but, I guess, while you were writing your response).

Comment: Do you know the answer when $G$ is cyclic of order 5?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is a famous problem, originating in work of de Rham, and the answer turns out to be No. The lowest-dimensional examples of non-linear similarity, as it is called, are in dimension 6, and examples only exist if the group has order divisible by (but not equal to) 4. This article contains a summary of the subject:

Sylvain Cappell, Julius Shaneson, Mark Steinberger, Shmuel Weinberger, and James West. [The classification of nonlinear similarities over ${\text{Z}}_{2^r}$](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1990-15837-9), Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society 22 (1990).

Mark Steinberger wrote another short summary of the subject, available here: http://math.albany.edu/topics/steinberger/msteinbergerrsch.pdf.

Comment: Are you by chance able to provide an explicit group (e.g., cyclic of order 8) and and explicit pair of non-equivalent representations that are topologically conjugate?

Comment: In principle I think one can work out an explicit example, e.g. for the cyclic group of order 8, from the information in Cappell and Shaneson's announcement https://www.projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-1/issue-6/Nonlinear-similarity-of-matrices/bams/1183544899.full

Comment: I hope someone will work out some such example and post it...

Comment: Oh, it's explicit in the original [Cappell-Shaneson paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/2006986). They provide many explicit examples, one of which (p318 pick $q=2$, $j=k=1$), for the cyclic group of order 8, is as follows: define $r_\theta$ as the rotation matrix of angle $2\pi\theta/8$ is given by the two 9-dimensional real representations given by powers of block-diagonal matrices $(r_1,r_1,r_1,r_1,-1)$ and $(r_5,r_5,r_5,r_5,-1)$.

Comment: Thanks! This is very surprising.